# Pandas drop rows if only first column has data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like so:

```
Unnamed:1 Unnamed:2 .... Unnamed:20
Data      NaN       .... NaN
id        name      .... year
.
.
.
Data2     NaN       .... NaN
id        name      .... year
.
.
.
Footnotes NaN       .... NaN
```

So, in order to clean this data, I first want to drop all rows where only the first column has data and rest all columns are NaN. So my dataframe will become like so:

```
Unnamed:1 Unnamed:2 .... Unnamed:20
id        name      .... year
.
.
.
id        name      .... year
.
.
.
```

Then make the first row as column names and drop any further occurrences of it and so finally my dataframe should be like this:

```
id        name      .... year
.
.
.
```

Comment: can you add a more represntative sample of your data? what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve it using the below code:

```
col1 = df.iloc[:, 0]
temp = df.iloc[:, 1:]
temp = temp.dropna(axis=0, how='all')
df = pd.merge(pd.DataFrame(col1), temp, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner')
df = df.drop_duplicates()
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.drop(df.index[0]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `startswith`:

```
# cache the id rows
second_row = df.iloc[1].values

# data rows
data_rows = df.iloc[:,0].str.startswith('Data')

# id rows
id_rows = df.iloc[:,0].eq('id')
# or might be better
# id_rows = df.eq(second_row).all(1)

# drop those rows
df = df[ ~(data_rows | id_rows)]

# rename columns
df.columns = second_row
```

Comment: this doesn't work if some rows don't start with 'Data'. I have edited my question to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

You can split the DataFrame up with a `groupby`, set the columns and drop the unnecessary rows and then join everything into the DataFrame you need. Check `isnull()` across the row and take the cumsum to form the groups.

```
print(df)
  Unnamed:1 Unnamed:2 Unnamed:20
0      Data       NaN        NaN
1        id      name       year
2       id1     name1      year1
3     Data2       NaN        NaN
4        id      name       year
5       id2     name2      year2
6       id3     name3      year3
```

---

```
l = []
for idx, gp in df.groupby(df.iloc[:, 1:].isnull().all(1).cumsum()):
    gp.columns = gp.iloc[1, :]   # Set columns
    gp = gp.iloc[2:]             # Remove Unnamed and col name rows
    l.append(gp)

res = pd.concat(l, ignore_index=True)
#    id   name   year
#0  id1  name1  year1
#1  id2  name2  year2
#2  id3  name3  year3
```

Comment: can you explain your answer further